# How to add element in the list after other element that clicked and have data atribute with specific value? with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

apologies if this is a duplicate, but I've searched for this specific question and haven't been able to find it.

Let's say I have 4 paragraphs i want add `<h3>` element under paragraph that was clicked.

each of  paragraphs have same data-name attribute but different value
i tried already  `$(" <h3 data-price'222'>NEW ITEM</h3>").insertAfter(???);`, but i don't know what write in the bracket.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <p class="clickable" data-price="5">Apple</p>
        <br>
        <p class="clickable" data-price="7">Coffee</p>
        <br>
        <p class="clickable" data-price="9">Water</p>
        <br>
        <p class="clickable" data-price="10">Pitza</p>
        <br>
        <h3></h3>
        <br>
        <button>Reset</button>

    </div>

</body>
```

```
$(function () {
    createCeleb();
})


function createCeleb() {
    $('p.clickable').on('click', function () {

        var temp = $(this).attr('data-price')
        this.temp = temp;
        let on1 = $("p").find(`[data-price='${this.temp}']`)
        $(" <h3 data-price'222'>NEW ITEM</h3>").insertAfter(on1);

    });
}
```

I expect that after I click on the paragraph
under will be added  element
but nothing happen 
I want it be dynamic and added only under paragraph that clicked
is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because

```
let on1 = $("p").find(`[data-price='${this.temp}']`);
```

does not find and thus return an object at all.

However there is a more elegant way to obtain the object which caused the click event than trying to find it using a data attribute.

If you add the special **e** parameter to the callback function you can reference the object using **e.target**.

Here's an example - just click on 'Run code snippet':

```js
    $('p.clickable').on('click', function (e) {
        var temp = $(this).attr('data-price')
        this.temp = temp;
        let on1 = e.target;
        $(" <h3 data-price'222'>NEW ITEM</h3>").insertAfter(on1);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

        <p class="clickable" data-price="5">Apple</p>
        <br>
        <p class="clickable" data-price="7">Coffee</p>
        <br>
        <p class="clickable" data-price="9">Water</p>
        <br>
        <p class="clickable" data-price="10">Pitza</p>
        <br>
        <h3></h3>
        <br>
        <button>Reset</button>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help Romka!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.  Create a new element from the HTML you had then add `after` the `<p>` that was clicked.

```
$(function () {
    createCeleb();
})


function createCeleb() {
    $('p.clickable').on('click', function () {
        var newele = $.parseHTML("<h3 data-price'222'>NEW iTEM</h3>");

        $(this).after(newele)

    });
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyddlywink/otmzycq8/)